# Submitting multipart/form-data in ScalaWS

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to create a post with 2 parts: the first part is a json text and the second, is the binary audio content.

The code to send the post is actually:

```
val ref = UUID.randomUUID()
val requestJobData = s"""
{
   "reference": "$ref",
   "operating_mode": "accurate",
   "callback_url": "http://localhost:8100/",
   "model": { "name": "por-bra" },
   "channels": {
       "firstChannelLabel": {
           "result_format": "transcript",
           "format":"audio/x-wav",
            "num_speakers":2,
        }
   }
}
  """
val jsonPart = DataPart("json", requestJobData)
val filePart = FilePart("firstChannelLabel", "audio(1).wav", Some("audio/x-wav"), FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("C:\\Input\\_pending\\audio(1).wav")))
val body = Source(filePart :: jsonPart :: List())

val response  =
  client.url(s"$baseUrl")
    .post(body)
    .map {response => response.body[String]}
```

When I try this code I get these errors:

```
Error:(73, 14) Cannot find an instance of akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[Product with Serializable with play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData.Part[akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString,scala.concurrent.Future[akka.stream.IOResult]]],akka.NotUsed] to WSBody. Define a BodyWritable[akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[Product with Serializable with play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData.Part[akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString,scala.concurrent.Future[akka.stream.IOResult]]],akka.NotUsed]] or extend play.api.libs.ws.ahc.DefaultBodyWritables
        .post(body)

Error:(73, 14) not enough arguments for method post: (implicit evidence$3: play.api.libs.ws.BodyWritable[akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[Product with Serializable with play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData.Part[akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString,scala.concurrent.Future[akka.stream.IOResult]]],akka.NotUsed]])scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.ws.StandaloneWSRequest#Response].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$3.
        .post(body)
```

My dependencies are:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.0" % Test
libraryDependencies += ws
libraryDependencies += guice

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.5.3" % Test
)


libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ahc-ws-standalone" % "1.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws-standalone-json" % "1.0.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.7.2"
)
```

Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am in the same boat. After some research, I believe the standalone version of WS Play does not include support for multipart requests yet. See this github issue: https://github.com/playframework/play-ws/issues/126

You get the compile error because no fitting BodyWritable exists.

Comment: Exactly. I had problems with BodyWritable too. I answered this question with my current setup, using another library.

Answer (score 1):

As I needed to accomplish this task faster, for this specific part I had to switch to another library called apache.http (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)

These are my current settings:

build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.3.1",
   "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpmime" % "4.3.1"
)
```

Complete POST example:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.{HttpGet, HttpPost}
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

val ref = UUID.randomUUID()
val requestJobData =
  s"""
{
   "reference": "$ref",
   "operating_mode": "accurate",
   "model": { "name": "por-bra" },
   "channels": {
       "firstChannelLabel": {
           "result_format": "lattice",
           "format":"audio/x-wav",
            "num_speakers":2
        }
   }
}
  """

val entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
entity.addTextBody("json", requestJobData, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)

val path = Paths.get(audioPath)
val fileName = path.getFileName().toString()
val fileStream = new FileInputStream(audioPath)
entity.addBinaryBody("firstChannelLabel", fileStream, ContentType.create("audio/x-wav"), fileName)
val client = HttpClients.createDefault()
try {
  val post = new HttpPost(baseUrl)
  post.setEntity(entity.build())
  val response = client.execute(post)
}
catch {
  case e: Throwable =>
    log.error("erro ao agendar job: " + e.toString())
}
finally {
  client.close()
}
```

It's really working. I omitted some parts of the code regarding communication with actors and other logging, but I hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative solution!